# Erlang script assigning variables

Tags: erlang

I am trying to assign a pseudo-random number seed to a variable. However, after I tried to assign the stringified seed to the variable, Erlang gave me an error:

```
code.erl:1: syntax error before: Number
escript: There were compilation errors.
```

This question might seem a bit foolish, but I have absolutely no idea how to get it working. Here's the old script. (I didn't realize that you can't define global variables outside of functions...)

```
Number = "7316717653133062491922511".

main([]) -> io:fwrite(Number).
```

Here's the new script:

```
Number() -> "7316717653133062491922511".

main([]) -> io:fwrite(Number()).
```

Answer (score 2):

In Erlang, function names start with a lower-case letter<sup>*</sup>, so this would work:

```
number() -> "7316717653133062491922511".

main([]) -> io:fwrite(number()).
```

There are no global variables; all variables must be assigned inside a function.

---

<sup>* Actually, a function name can contain any character if you single-quote it: `'Number'()`.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can’t define global variables outside of functions as with Number in your first example.